# Rails Device "Fingerprinting"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fingerprint, identification

Is there any way or best practice around device fingerprinting for a rails app?  In other words.  Given that all cookies are blocked, is there any way, with a relatively good degree of certainty, who the person is before they log in?

My assumption: IPs are unreliable for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 2):

We've setup device fingerprinting in our rails app using ThreatMetrix.com
They are sort of expensive, but used by a number of large sites on the web and have built some good technology around this.

I have seen some Jquery open source released for this crop up: https://github.com/carlo/jquery-browser-fingerprint
But have not tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Fingerprintjs2](https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2). It is quite useful in trying to uniquely identifying a browser.

Answer (score -1):

Even if all cookies are blocked, javascript can pick up plenty of [device attributes](http://noc.to/).

Comment: Link is broken.